# How to delete Django migration files in Dokku?

Tags: django, docker, dokku

In a normal world, you can access your application folder and delete files and folders. For Django migration files, the following code can be applied:

```
find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name "__init__.py" -delete
find . -path "*/migrations/*.pyc"  -delete
```

But in Dokku, everything is in a container that I have no idea how to access. So how can I delete migration files?

Answer (score 0):

In Dokku there is a command to destroy/delete apps

```
apps:destroy <app>
```

Ref link: https://github.com/dokku/dokku/blob/master/docs/deployment/application-management.md

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't want to destroy the whole app. I just want to delete few files.

Answer (score 0):

Dokku builds application's based on the repository contents, so you'll need to `git rm` the files (and commit the removals) from your repository and deploy the updated version in order to ensure they do not end up in the deployed container.